# magento saving admin details

Tags: magento

I'm wondering if its possible to programmatically save admin user details? email, password, first name, last name and password.

This is what I have so far:

```
$details = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
$details->setEmail($postData['email'])
         ->setFirstName($postData['first_name'])
         ->setLastName($postData['last_name']);

if($postData['password']) {
    if($postData['password'] === $postData['password_confirm']) {
        $details->setPassword($postData['password']);
    }
}
$details->save();
```

However, it's not saving (it is saving other details). It is also not generating any errors.

Comment: ***DON'T SAVE PLAIN-TEXT PASSWORDS!!!*** It's a _major_ security risk, both for your application and for others. Instead, save a hash of the password.

Comment: I thought Magento would take care of that? Cos that's what I saw somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working:

```
$details = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
$model = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($details2->getUserId());

$model->setEmail($postData['email'])
         ->setFirstname($postData['firstname'])
         ->setLastname($postData['lastname']);

if($postData['password']) {
    if($postData['password'] === $postData['password_confirm']) {
        $model->setPassword($postData['password']);
    }
}
$model->save();
```